# Why do I get IllegalArgumentException Cannot convert value of type String to required type Product, in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, illegalargumentexception

**I receive the exception**

> Failed to convert property value of
>   type [java.lang.String] to required
>   type [beans.Product] for property
>   product; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.lang.String] to required type
>   [beans.Product] for property product:
>   no matching editors or conversion
>   strategy found

**in the Errors errors object even before my DetailProductValidator starts validating through the validate method.**

I don't understand why Spring does that. I don't have any input field that is mapped directly to the product property/object. I just use the product object's properties in the jsp. For example, I use:

```
<form:options items="${dpBackObj.product.colorMap}"/>
<!-- or -->
${dpBackObj.product.priceInDollars}
```

but I never use:

```
<form:input path="product"/>
```

**Can anyone please explain why this happens? And maybe inform me of a simple solution?**

The bean configuration for the controller is:

```
    <!-- DETAIL PRODUCT FORM CONTROLLER -->
<bean id="productDetailFormController" name="/detail.htm /addToCart.htm" 
        class="detailProduct.DetailProductFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true" />
    <property name="commandName" value="dpBackObj" />
    <property name="commandClass" value="detailProduct.DetailProductBackingObject" />
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="detailProduct.DetailProductValidator" />
    </property>
    <property name="formView" value="detail" />
    <property name="successView" value="redirect:/viewCart.htm" />
    <property name="cartService" ref="cartServiceImpl"/>
</bean>
```

The backing object for the DetailProductFormController is:

```
public class DetailProductBackingObject {
    private String quantityOverflowError;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
    private long sizeId;
    private long colorId;
    public DetailProductBackingObject() {
        this.product = new Product();
        this.sizeId = -1;
        this.colorId = -1;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

If you need some other info, I will provide. I am using Spring 2.5.5.

Kind Regards,
Despot

**EDIT1** (*due to request from axtavt*):

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="dpBackObj">
<table width="730" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <c:if test="${!empty dpBackObj.quantityOverflowError}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:out value="${dpBackObj.quantityOverflowError}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:if>
    <spring:bind path="dpBackObj.*">
        <c:if test="${not empty status.errorMessages}">
            <div class="val-summary text-error" id="errorDivId">
                <div style="" class="val-summary text-error" id="errorDivId">
                    <fmt:message key="detail.error.header"/>
                    <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                            <li><c:out value="${error}"/></li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </c:if>
    </spring:bind>
    <tr>
        <td width="310" align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="${imagesPath}/${dpBackObj.product.largeImageUrl}" alt="${dpBackObj.product.description}" />
        </td>
        <td width="420" align="left" valign="top">
            <div id="tls_detPName">
                <c:out value="${dpBackObj.product.name}"></c:out>
            </div>
            <div >  
                <strong class="numeric">${dpBackObj.product.priceInDollars}</strong>
            </div>
            <div id="tls_detPDescLong">
                ${dpBackObj.product.largeDescription}
                <br />
            </div>
            <div >
                <table cellpadding="2" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <label for="p_sizes" class="label"><fmt:message key="viewCart.Size"/></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:select path="sizeId" > 
                                <form:option  value="-1" label="x"/> 
                                <form:options items="${dpBackObj.product.sizeMap}"/>
                            </form:select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <label for="p_colors" class="label"><fmt:message key="viewCart.Color"/></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form:select path="colorId" > 
                                <form:option value="-1" label="y"/> 
                                <form:options items="${dpBackObj.product.colorMap}"/>
                            </form:select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="tls_addToCart">
                <div >
                    <label for="quantityId" class="label"><fmt:message key="viewCart.Quantity"/>:</label>
                    <form:input path="quantity" onkeypress="return checkForNumber(this, event)" maxlength="10" size="3" id="quantityId" cssClass="textbox-center"/>
                    <input type="image" name="addToCartButtonName" src="${imagesPath}/addToCartBtn.jpg" /> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

**EDIT2** (*due to JacobM's request*):
This is my Validator:

```
public class DetailProductValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return DetailProductBackingObject.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        DetailProductBackingObject detailProductBackingObject = (DetailProductBackingObject) obj;
        if (detailProductBackingObject.getSizeId() == -1) {
            errors.rejectValue("sizeId", "error.detail.jsp.choose.size", null, "Input size.");
        }
    }
}
```

When I reach the line *DetailProductBackingObject detailProductBackingObject =* I already have the error.
The converting of the request parameters to the backing object properties happens in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/BaseCommandController.html . This is what Spring says about the conversion:

> Populating using request parameters
>   and PropertyEditors: Upon receiving a
>   request, any BaseCommandController
>   will attempt to fill the command
>   object using the request parameters.
>   This is done using the typical and
>   well-known JavaBeans property
>   notation. When a request parameter
>   named 'firstName' exists, the
>   framework will attempt to call
>   setFirstName([value]) passing the
>   value of the parameter. Nested
>   properties are of course supported.
>   For instance a parameter named
>   'address.city' will result in a
>   getAddress().setCity([value]) call on
>   the command class.
>
> It's important to realise that you are
>   not limited to String arguments in
>   your JavaBeans. Using the
>   PropertyEditor-notion as supplied by
>   the java.beans package, you will be
>   able to transform Strings to Objects
>   and the other way around. For instance
>   setLocale(Locale loc) is perfectly
>   possible for a request parameter named
>   locale having a value of en, as long
>   as you register the appropriate
>   PropertyEditor in the Controller (see
>   initBinder() for more information on
>   that matter.
>
> Validators: After the controller has
>   successfully populated the command
>   object with parameters from the
>   request, it will use any configured
>   validators to validate the object.
>   Validation results will be put in a
>   Errors object which can be used in a
>   View to render any input problems.

Comment: Actually, what I'd like to see is the controller method that the form is submitted to.  That's the spot where Spring is likely to try to turn a form submission consisting of strings into an actual Product object.

Comment: Hi JacobM, since I don't convert the request parameters to the backing object's propoerties myself (I don't have a dedicated method/class for that), I cannot provide this for you. This is done by Spring and the only explanation we have is the one that I wrote in EDIT2. From this, I cannot see why Spring would want to convert some String to the Product property of the backing object. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try catching the request as it is submitted (Firebug is a good way) and looking at all of the parameters.  Is there a parameter called "product"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I can't see anything wrong with the form, the only possible reason I can imagine is that you have a parameter named `product` in the URL of your form page.

If so, you can change your URLs or use `DataBinder.setDisallowedFields()` to disable the attempt to bind that parameter.

Comment: Hi axtavt, so true!!! I forgot that the client sends those values in the request ... talking about thinking out of the box! Thanks a bunch!!!
P.S.: I already changed the controller logic to work with the properties of the product, instead of using the product object directly, but I so wanted to know what was going on with Spring... I think I will change it back now ;)